# Using Selenium2, how do I check if certain text exists on the page?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using the C# Selenium WebDriver and I would like to confirm that certain text exists on the page.

How do I do this? All the selectors seem to use IDs, Classes etc. I don't care where the text is on the page, I just want to make sure it exists *somewhere* on the page.

Any thoughts?

PS: I can do this using JQuery and Javascript, but apparently that's not supported in all browser drivers:

```
protected bool TextIsOnThePage(string textToFind)
{
    var javascriptExecutor = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)_driver);
    bool textFound = Convert.ToBoolean(javascriptExecutor.ExecuteScript(string.Format("return $('*:contains(\"{0}\")').length > 0", textToFind)));

    return textFound;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
WebElement bodyTag = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")); 
if (bodyTag.getText().contains("Text I am looking for") { 
  // do something 
}
```

or find a speific div

or you can use the Selenium class WebDriverBasedSelenium and do something like

```
var selenium=new WebDriverBasedSelenium(driver,url);

selenium.IsTextPresent("text")
```

Comment: good answer, alternatively you can use html instead of body, I've had a couple cases were html worked better

Answer (score 8):

Here's an updated version using  [Selenium WebDriver 2.48.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver)

```
IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(DesiredCapabilities.Firefox());
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://stackoverflow.com/");
IWebElement body = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body"));

Assert.IsTrue(body.Text.Contains("Top Questions"));
```

Note: The Assert is an Nunit assert, you can obviously use whichever assertion method you prefer. I'm also using the RemoteWebDriver and Firefox for this example.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this by checking the inner text of `<body />`.

Answer (score 0):

In java you do it like so:

boolean whatever = driver.getPageSource().contains("Whatever your trying to find");

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing I found was to search for a class

```
IWebElement thing = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("thingClass"));

Assert.IsTrue(thing.Text.Contains("YourText"));
```